# Microsoft Graph - Get Token from Authorisation Response

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am following the instructions here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user?view=graph-rest-1.0#3-get-a-token

I get the authorisation response and therefore the required code, but when I request the token I get a "HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized" response.

This is my code (not for production, just for me to get the flow/code right first):

```
<?php
/*
    Auth
    https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user?view=graph-rest-1.0
*/

define("HOST",              'https://login.microsoftonline.com');
define("TENANT",            'common');
define("AUTH_ENDPOINT",     HOST.'/'.TENANT.'/oauth2/v2.0/authorize');
define("TOKEN_ENDPOINT",    HOST.'/'.TENANT.'/oauth2/v2.0/token');
define("CLIENT_ID",         '<< FROM AZURE PORTAL >>');
define("CLIENT_SECRET",     '<< FROM AZURE PORTAL >>');
define("ALL_SCOPES",        rawurlencode('offline_access user.read mail.read'));
define("CALLBACK",          rawurlencode('http://localhost:300/graph2/auth.php'));

// Build URL
$url = AUTH_ENDPOINT."?client_id=".CLIENT_ID;
$url .= "&response_type=code";
$url .= "&redirect_uri=".CALLBACK;
$url .= "&response_mode=query";
$url .= "&scope=".ALL_SCOPES;

echo "<a href=$url>$url</a>";

if (isset($_GET))
{
    echo '<pre>';print_r($_GET);echo'</pre>';

    if (isset($_GET['code']))
    {
        // Got authorisation code - now need token
        $response = requestAccessTokenByVerifier($_GET['code']);
        echo ">".$response;
    }
}

function requestAccessTokenByVerifier($verifier)
{
    return requestAccessToken(
        array(
            'client_id' => CLIENT_ID,
            'redirect_uri' => CALLBACK,
            'client_secret' => CLIENT_SECRET,
            'code' => $verifier,
            'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
            'scope' => ALL_SCOPES
        )
    );
  }

function requestAccessToken($content) 
{
    $response = sendRequest(TOKEN_ENDPOINT, 'POST', $content);
  
    if ($response !== false)
    {
        $authToken = json_decode($response);
        if (!empty($authToken) && !empty($authToken->{ACCESSTOKEN})) return $authToken;
    }
  
    die("No access token");
    return false;
  }

function sendRequest($url, $method = 'GET', $data = array(), $headers = array('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'))
{
    $context = stream_context_create(
        array(
            'http' => array(
                'method' => $method,
                'header' => $headers,
                'content' => buildQueryString($data)
            )
        )
    );

    echo "URL: $url<br>";
    echo '<pre>';print_r($data);echo '</pre>';
    echo buildQueryString($data)."<br>";
    $response = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
    echo '<pre>';var_dump($http_response_header);echo '</pre>';
    return $response;
}

function buildQueryString($array)
{
    $result = '';
    foreach ($array as $k => $v)
    {
        if ($result == '') $prefix = ''; else $prefix = '&';
        $result .= $prefix . $k . '=' . $v;
    }
    return $result;
}
?>
```

As you will see I've put a few basic diagnostics in there which show I am getting the code required successfully, but then not being able to get a token from the code.

Can anybody suggest what to try next, I wonder either from a debugging point of view or alternative approaches.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, after digging around I realised I'd made a stupid mistake, but just in case anybody else does the same - you need to use the client secret value not id!

[image]

I've deleted that client secret :)

Hope that helps somebody else bashing their head against a brick wall.

Answer (score 0):

What I do is run the API request from Postman as it is easier to use and then on the top right select the code icon, choose your programming language and Postman will tell you the correct syntax.